# Can't change Ruby Version with RubyMine Terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I have a weird problem with the terminal in RubyMine. In my previously created project, RubyMine worked fine, the project ruby version is automatically set at 3.2.3 after using rails new.

 For some reason, when I create this project, the terminal in RubyMine run with ruby version 3.2.2 even though I have set the global version with rbenv to 3.2.3. I can't use the bundler to install newest version of gems as it says `Your Ruby version is 3.2.2, but your Gemfile specified 3.2.3`. I don't want to use 3.2.2.

When I open the same project with VsCode and use the VsCode terminal to check, the ruby version is correctly set at 3.2.3, using rbenv versions also show that it is at 3.2.3.
First image is in VsCode, second image is in RubyMine. Same project.

[VsCode Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9xOF.png) 
[RubyMine Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc0sI.png)

I tried using rbenv global 3.2.3, rbenv local 3.2.3, rbenv shell 3.2.3 in RubyMine Terminal but nothing changes.

Solution: Change the version of Ruby by going to Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Ruby SDK and Gems

Comment: Could you check which Ruby version is set for the project in Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Ruby SDK and Gems.

Comment: @Olivia I checked and for some reason it is 3.2.2. I changed it to 3.2.3 and it worked. Thank you very much